# Iniciar DevTools com opções personalizadas no Electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, electron

Na minha aplicação eu tenho uma função `developerMode()` que faz a chamada do DevTools

```
function developerMode() {
  var r = confirm(lang.developerModeConfirm);
  if (r == true) {
    remote.getCurrentWindow().toggleDevTools();
    app.mode = 'dev'
    console.log(lang.developerModeOn)
  } else {
    console.log(lang.developerModeOff)
  }
}
```

Seria possível que essa função iniciasse o DevTools com algumas configurações padrões? Há uma forma de habilitar somente o Console? Acho que o DevTools nativo é muito poderoso e faz o que eu preciso, porém não tem nada a ver visualmente com minha aplicação, não queria ter que reescrever um console personalizado.

Answer (score 0):

Olá,

Pelo que vi na documentação do electron carrega todo o devtools, o máximo que você consegue fazer é adicionar alguma extensão, talvez tenha alguma que utiliza apenas o console: [https://electron.atom.io/docs/tutorial/devtools-extension/][1]